# How can I manage connection loss during the communication between my android application and the webservice?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am working on android project which communicate with a webservice in order to receive datas and store them into the database.

Before the sending operation, I verify the connection state (see the code below)

```
if (XXX.getInstance(Context).isOnline(Context)) 
{
//TODO Sending operation
}
```

But during this operation if the device is offline I lose datas though the HTTP status code is 200 or 201.

***I manage before the operation but not during.***

> Is there a way to figure this out?

Comment: If I provided you with the answer, please mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

Use a broadcast receiver to constantly check the status of the connection.

First register the receiver in your `onCreate()` method:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

Then write what you want to do when your desired signal has been discovered:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) 
        {
        //You are still connected
        }
        else
        {
        //You have lost connection
        }
    }
};
```

Make sure you unregister the receiver once you leave the activity (in the `onDestroy()`) method:

```
if (mReceiver != null)
{
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Comment: This checks that the device is connected to the internet using Wi-Fi or 3G.